# Google Play Services Multiplayer Participant's Identity

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am working on a game using Google Play Services real-time multiplayer. Everything is working fine however the participants always have generic names. I need to show their names but instead of showing usernames it shows some generic player_[somenumber].

I am using test accounts, both test accounts have given public access to the app. Their display names show perfectly on their own mobiles but it doesn't show on the other player's mobile.

The API reference says

> If the identity of the player is unknown, this will be a generic handle to describe the player.

I want to know, what are the cases when the identity of the player is unknowing while the game is being played.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The identity of a person is unknown to a user when they are not in the user's circles. In such cases you will get a generic handle and no profile picture.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I thought I might be able to get user's info. Guess I cant do that.

Answer (score 2):

In automach game also person in my circle have obfuscated id.